# Object.assign in map returns unexpected response with extra information

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to systematically replace the key value in a JSON object with a new value that I calculate:

```
newReport = filteredReport

  sumFunc = (items, prop) => {
       return items.reduce( function(a, b){
              return a + b[prop];
     }, 0);
 }

 complete = newReport.map((v,i) => {
    let newValue = sumFunc(newReport[i].like, 'value')  
    //return { ...v, like: newValue } 
    return Object.assign({}, v, {like: newValue})

 })
```

filteredReport, i.e., the original value, is a result of a query from MongoDB.

When I run this function, I get a response that's 340,000 lines long. The correct result is in place in the last line, but I get a lot of other undesired information in there that is unexpected.

Why do I receive this information?

This is a sample of the response: https://codepen.io/schoenbl/pen/pXVRBq?editors=0010#0

**EDIT:**
When I use spread and Object.assign, I receive the same result.

**Another Edit:**
When I preview it outside, it works correctly:
https://playcode.io/360520?tabs=script.js,preview,console

**Last Edit:**
This is my mongo query:

```
const report = await Report.find({createdAt: { $gt: startDate, $lt: Date() }})
    .populate({path: 'like'})
    .populate({
        path: 'player',
        populate: [{ path: 'team' },
        {
            path: 'team',
            populate: {
                path: 'league'
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: is `filteredReport` a model instance?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty it's a response from a mongo query, which comes from a model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you query it returns an array Mongoose document instance. But when you  console log it shows you the `toString` representation of it. But actually, it contains all those functions properties of the Document class instance to do further operations. To return only data use [`.lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) when querying.

```
Report.find().lean().exec(function (err, report) {
    ....
}
```

This will return only the plain js object of the data that you want. Not all the class properties and methods.

**Tip:** To know what a variable really contains, use `console.dir` instead of `console.log`

Comment: How would you configure that with my mongo query? Just added in a last edit.

Comment: try to just add `.lean()` at the end. that should do it.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Worked perfect!